# Apache POI -Read from Excel Exceptions in Selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

If an exception occurs while fetching the data from the excel, will the execution stops? Only the current test case or all the test cases?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG behave differently for exceptions appearing on different stages, so it depends.

Basically, no matter which exception appeared (unless testng SkipException, but it's the edge case, so i miss this), you might get the next:

**Before configurations**
For this case all dependent test and configuration methods will be skipped (unless some of them have `alwaysRun=true` annotation attribute).

**Test method**
You'll get this test failed. Also all the tests, which depends on this method will be skipped.

**After configurations**
Usually this do not affect your test results, but may fail the build, even all the tests passed. And also after confirmation failures may potentially affect some ongoing tests, if they expect something (but this is not related to TestNG functionality).

**DataProvider**
All the related tests will be skipped, everything else will not be affected.

**Test Class constructor**
This will broke your run, no tests will be executed.

**Factory method (need to recheck)**
I don't remember the behaviour. This might fail the whole launch or just some test classes. But exception here is a serious issue, try to avoid.

**TestNG Listeners**
This will broke the whole your test launch. Try to implement them error-free, surrounding with try/catches.